# How to get dom object of current component in Polymer.js 2.0?

Tags: dom, polymer-2.x

I defined component of polymer.js 2.0.
and inside member function of this component, I would like to get current component content as dom object after dom ready. is this possbile?
How can I get dom object of current component after it attached to document?

Answer (score 0):

Since any Custom Element is an HTML element, `this` is a reference to the DOM object. Custom Elements created with the Polymer library are no different in this regard.

All the methods and properties of the `HTMLElement` prototype are available inside member functions of a Polymer Element:

```js
_onClick() {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = 'hi there!';
  this.appendChild(span);
}
```

Here is a simple JSFiddle for this example: https://jsfiddle.net/vlukashov/oyr5bpyk/